# Implement a method public static String nameOfBestCustomer(ArrayList<Double> sales, ArrayList<String< customers)

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the only part of the problem I have done which only reads a list of values in from the user and then prints all and points to the largest input. I'm confused on how to group together the arraylist of the specific customer with their specific name. 
The actual problem:  this method should return the name of the customer with the largest sale.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();

    System.out.println("Enter the customers purchase amount, Q to quit");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextDouble()){
        values.add(in.nextDouble());
    }

    double largest = values.get(0);
    for (int i =1; i< values.size(); i++){
        if (values.get(i) > largest){
            largest = values.get(i);
        }

    }
    for (double element : values){
        System.out.print(element);
        if (element == largest){
            System.out.println("   <===largest value");


        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: A desirable solution would include defining `customerName` and `periodSales` as instance fields in a class named (for example) `Customer`.  If `Customer` instances have a natural order, then you should also define a compator for them also.  Then it would be easy to manipulate your `Customer` objects in a collection of `List<Customer> sales = new ArrayList<Customer>();`.  The code you present would likely benefit from greater object orientation.

Answer (score 0):

1: We dont know how the customer name will be set in the program; whether its user input or somehow created in another way.

2:If a customer can hold many input,the Easiest way to solve this is creating the customer class and have it hold a String name and a list of Input

```
class Customer{
String name;
List<Integer> inputs=new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer max;
public Customer(String name){
 this.name=name
 }
 public void sort(){
  ///sort code here
  //set variable max to the max value in the inputs array
 }
}
```

then you can create Customer in your main class such as this:

```
List<Customer> list=new ArrayList<Customer>();
Customer customer1=new Customer("Brian");
Customer customer2=new Customer("Asura")

and then add order amount to any customer depending how you want.
customer1.inputs.add(999)
customer2.inputs.add(23123);
```

then you need to compare all customer; call the sort method of every customer

```
for(Customer aCustomer:list)
  aCustomer.sort();
```

you now have the max variable set for every customer objects; now compare them;easiest would be to use comparable but may be too advanced for beginner so heres a different way.

```
Customer result; //will hold the object with highest input
int maximum=0;
for(Customer aCustomer:list)
    if(aCustomer.max>maximum){
       result=aCustomer;
       maximum=aCustomer.max
}
```

we now have the customer object containing the maximum

```
System.out.println(result.name+" maximum:"+result.max);
```

Comment: That's the problem I'm having. I can create another code similar to this but just with inputs of customers. I haven't created the customer part. I'm confused how to assign which customer name matches their price. My skill level is very moderate beginner. I was thinking I would create two arraylists. Specify which space in the array the largest value is and then match that space with the same space in the string arraylist. There's probably an easier way to do this but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to associate some user name with list of doubles. This can be done using `Map<String, List<Double>>`. So you can declare it like:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> user2values = new HashMap<>();
```

And add the value using the following method:

```
void addValue(String user, double value) {
    List<Double> values = user2values.get(user);
    if(values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList<>();
        user2values.put(user, values);
    }
    values.add(value);
}
```

Or shorter if you are using Java 8:

```
void addValue(String user, double value) {
    user2values.computeIfAbsent(user, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

After that you will have values grouped by user. If you want to scan it for the biggest value, you can do the following:

```
String getMaxValueUser() {
    String bestUser = null;
    double maxValue = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry : user2values.entrySet()) {
        for(Double value : entry.getValue()) {
            if(value > maxValue) {
                value = maxValue;
                bestUser = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    return bestUser;
}
```

Or shorter if you are using Java 8:

```
String getMaxValueUser() {
    return user2values.entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue()
                    .stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).max()
                    .orElse(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY))).map(Entry::getKey)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

public static String nameOfBestCustomer(ArrayList sales, ArrayList customers) {

```
Double largestSale = 0.0;
int largestIndex = 0;

for(Double s: sales) {
    largestSale = Math.max(largestSale, s);
}

largestIndex = sales.indexOf(largestSale);

return customers.get(largestIndex);
```

}

Comment: This answer would only work assuming the name of the customer is associated with the same index with its sales.
Such as:
sales.get(0) is for customers.get(0)